# Running multiple tests in a Single spec is throwing Webdriver.Quit error

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am running multiple tests in a single Spec. When I reach to one of the function, It throws the error `WebDriver.Quit()`. Function is about validating the fields in a form (Readonly form). I have multiple `getText().then` (Function) for validating each field against expected output. Which I am passing as a parameter to the function. And logging the output of the Expected and Actual output.

When I comment other tests and run only this test, it is executing perfectly without any issues. Note: I have set property to restart the browser between each test as true in my config file.

Comment: If you are facing this issue on running the whole suite and the not on running the single test case. Then there might be some dependency with other cases.

Comment: also can you confirm that you are getting this error too?                                      throw new Error('This driver instance does not have a valid session ID '

Comment: {throw new Error('This driver instance does not have a valid session ID '}

Comment: would it be possible for you to include the whole error trace?

Comment: one more info needed too. So that i can come with some solution for your problem. Node version, protractor version, framework jasmine/cucumber and its version, webdriver version for that browser and your OS and its version.